# Remove a script using Id

Tags: javascript, typescript, script-tag

I have the below script which I am embedding and removing to embed the next one. however I want remove the previous tag by id and not head.childNodes[head.childNodes.length - 1]. Can anyone pls help.

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.type = 'text/javascript';
    tag.id = 'adobedatalayer'
    tag.textContent = "var DDO = {}; DDO.pageData = {'pageName': '" + pageLoadData.pageUrl + "'} ";
    if (this._dataLayerInjected) {
      var script = head.childNodes[head.childNodes.length - 1]; //get previous script element
      head.removeChild(script); //removing script
      head.appendChild(tag); // appending the script again
    } else {
      head.appendChild(tag);
      this._dataLayerInjected = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.type = 'text/javascript';
    tag.id = 'adobedatalayer';
    tag.textContent = 'var DDO = {}; DDO.pageData =' + JSON.stringify(pageinfo);
    var script = document.getElementById('adobedatalayer');
    if (script != null) {
      head.removeChild(script);
    }
    head.appendChild(tag);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about you just keep a reference to the script tag when you insert it, and then you can `.remove()` it the next time this section of code runs? Put it on the instance rather than saving a `_dataLayerInjected` flag. You can also use `document.head` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];`:

```
// Remove previous script:
if (this.script) {
  this.script.remove();
}
this.script = document.createElement('script');
this.script.id = 'adobedatalayer'; // is this really needed?
this.script.textContent = "var DDO = {}; DDO.pageData = {'pageName': '" + pageLoadData.pageUrl + "'} ";
document.head.appendChild(this.script);
```